# Different font size in Label in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I would like to display a set of Text like this **"DISCONTINUED (02-02-2012) Crocin"** in label. But i need smaller font size for Date. How can I set the value to Label so that I can display smaller size font for Date.

I only need to assign a single string to label? like this **"DISCONTINUED (02-02-2012) Crocin"**

Is this possible in flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its possible in FLEX by 2 ways.

(1)

```
<mx:Text width="550">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
        <b><font size="26">DISCONTINUED </font><font size="18">(02-02-2012) Crocin</font>
        ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

(2)

Embed htmlText in Text area and change the CSS file as follows to feel like a Label. Change its selectable and editable property to false and don't forget to give height and width.

```
TextArea 
{
    leading: 0;
    backgroundAlpha: 0;
    borderStyle: none;
}
```

For more CSS changes visit [THIS LINK](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html)

Have a nice Day

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Take a look at this document from Adobes LiveDoc:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:Text width="550">
        <mx:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[
            <b><font size="26">DISCONTINUED </font><font size="18">(02-02-2012) Crocin</font>
            ]]>
        </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

You can also bring htmlText in label also.

```
<mx:Label width="600" height="100">
        <mx:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[
            <b><font size="26">DISCONTINUED </font><font size="18">(02-02-2012) Crocin</font>
            ]]>
        </mx:htmlText>
    </mx:Label>
```